# How do i sort Nested JSON Objects using Gson Library?

Tags: android, json, gson

am trying to parse my JSON data which looks like the data below.
I've successfully some fields but am trying to get"name" under "0" under "category" under "terms".

```
[
    {
    "ID": 1710,
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum",
    "parent": null,
    "format": "standard",
    "modified_tz": "UTC"
    },
    "featured_image": {
    "ID": 1713,
    "title": "km",
    "status": "inherit",
    "type": "attachment",
    }
    }
    }
    }
    },
    "terms": {
    "category": [    <<<<---AM REFERENCING HERE--->>>>>
    {
    "ID": 2,
    "name": "Entertainment",
    "slug": "entertainment",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "parent": null,
    "count": 30,
    }
    ]

    }
    }
    ]
```

This is how i parsed the data:

```
List<Object> list = (List) new Gson.fromJson(response, List.class);
List<String, Object> mapPost = list.get(index);
List<String, Object> terms = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("terms");
List<String, Object> category= (Map<String, Object>) terms.get("category");
List<String, Object> zero= (Map<String, Object>) category.get("0");
String tag = (String) zero.get("name");
```

Pleas help me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it should be `category.get(0)`. `0` is an index for the array not a key for the json

Comment: Here's the Error Message i got:

Comment: 'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: example.example.com, PID: 13804
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map'

Comment: I missed it earlier but your code shouldn't even compile? List<String, Object> is not valid syntax... So you should have been getting the error even before the change I suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided cannot even compile (broken `Gson` constructor invocation; Java does not provide `List<K,V>`...). Lists cannot be cast to maps in runtime too. The JSON is broken as well, but, assuming you've provided some code, I think you wanted to parse the `name` located at `$[(index)].terms.category[0].name`:

```java
    final String name = gson.fromJson(response, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray()
            .get(index).getAsJsonObject()
            .get("terms").getAsJsonObject()
            .get("category").getAsJsonArray()
            .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .get("name").getAsJsonPrimitive()
            .getAsString();
    System.out.println(name);
```

You don't need to deserialize each nested object you're going to traverse (and this is more efficient from the performance point of view): just traverse the JSON tree.

Comment: Since it's not certain that the user will include a tag (i.e `final String name`), i surrounded the code above, in a try catch block, is that okay?

Comment: It depends. You can break the chain and analyze its chunks apart.

Comment: I want to avoid breaking it down. Will try/catch be Okay? does it have performance implications?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution:

Since the "category" tag contain an array of JSON object (in this case a single object).

i cast the "category" into an arraylist

```
Map<String, Object> terms = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("terms");
ArrayList category = new ArrayList();
category = ((ArrayList) terms.get("category")); //<--Cast to ArrayList
zero  = (Map<String, Object>) category.get(0);
```

Then i got the "name" tag by doing:

```
String tag = (String) zero.get("name")
```